# How to test Tkinter label callback

Tags: python, tkinter

### Backgournd

I'm trying to learn how to use Tkinter.
For that I created a small application and I'm tying to create a unit test, using Pytest.

### The part I'm trying to test

There is a part that creates a label and sets a timeout for it, once that timeout reaches, the label is destroyed but I see that the callback to destroy is never called

#### Defining the callback

This par of a bigger method

```
        self.labels = deque()
        myLabel.after(timeout, myLabel.destroy)
        self.labels.appendleft(myLabel)
```

#### Unit test

```
class MockedClass(myTkinterApp):
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        self.label_timeout = label_timeout
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.labels = deque()

def test_timeout_reached_label_destroyed():
    obj = MockedClass(label_timeout=1)
    time.sleep(2)
    assert obj.labels[0].winfo_exists() is False
```

What I see is that the callback is never called.
What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think `after()` works unless the tkinter `mainloop` is running. From the code in your question, it doesn't look like it is. If it is, calling `time.sleep()` would also prevent it from working properly because calling that when `mainloop` is running would stop the loop for the duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a callback to be called, tkinter must process events on the event queue. This is the primary job of `mainloop`. Without the existence of `mainloop`, you can request that tkinter process all events by calling the `update` method of the root window.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. 
But now there is another problem.
I'll ask it on a different question

Comment: If you have time, take a look at the follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581233/how-to-test-tkinter-label-callback-follow-up